# Create React App not working on WebOs 3.0 (Chrome 38)

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, webos

When using create react app on WebOs 3.0 (Chrome 38 (I´m using chromium 39 for testing on the PC)) just the default example I get :

`main.chunk.js:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.`

And the example does not work.

Standar React app (No CRA) worked as expected.

I tried to eject but I found nothing, any idea what could be causing the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by react refresh package.
My workaround is using npm run eject and modyfing the file webpack.config.js => const shouldUseReactRefresh = false;